# How to create UICollectionView with alternating cell amount layout?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am developing an iPad app that uses UICollectionView to display a list of products from a company. The cells layout that I want to use is alternating between rows with 1 image and 2 images, like first row 1 image, second row 2 images, third row 1 image... and so on, but I just can't figure out how to do this in code.

So can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I manage to get it working with this code:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 30;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Cells *cell;

if (indexPath.row %2) {
    NSLog(@"%li", indexPath.row);
    cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"one" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = @"One";
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return cell;
} else {
    NSLog(@"%li", indexPath.row);
    cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"two" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.labelA.text = @"Two";
    cell.labelB.text = @"Two";
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}

}
```